# Why is my program not quitting when I ask it to?

Tags: java, methods, while-loop, calculator

I created a 4-function calculator. Everything works except for when I ask it to quit, it will not, it just continues asking for arg1 and arg2. I set up a while loop to get it to continuously run, however it should exit the program when I type "quit". What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calc{
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   boolean done = true;
  while (done == true) {
        System.out.println("Enter operator: + - * / or quit: "); //gets operator
    String operator = scan.next();

    System.out.println("Enter arg1: "); //gets the first argument
    double arg1 = scan.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Enter arg2: "); //gets the second argument
    double arg2 = scan.nextDouble();

    if (operator.equals("+")) {
        add(arg1, arg2);
    }
    if (operator.equals("-")) {
        minus(arg1, arg2);
    }
    if (operator.equals("*")) {
        multiply(arg1, arg2);
    }
    if (operator.equals("/")) {
        divide(arg1, arg2);

    }
    if (operator.equals("quit")) {
        System.out.println("Thank you for using the CSC 220 calculator!");
        done = false;

    }
    if((!operator.equals("+")) && (!operator.equals("-") && (!operator.equals("/")) && (!operator.equals("*")) && (!operator.equals("quit")))) {
        System.out.println("Error. That is not a supported operator.");
    }
    
}
}
    static void divide (double arg1, double arg2){
        System.out.println(arg1 + "/" + arg2 + " = " + (arg1 / arg2));
    

    }

    static void multiply (double arg1, double arg2){
        System.out.println(arg1 + " * " + arg2 + " = " + (arg1 * arg2));
    

    }

    static void add (double arg1, double arg2){
        System.out.println(arg1 + " + " + arg2 + " = " + (arg1 + arg2));
    

    }

    static void minus (double arg1, double arg2){
        System.out.println(arg1 + " - " + arg2 + " = " + (arg1 - arg2));

    }
}
```

Comment: If you want the `quit` code to run after you enter an operator but before you enter the arguments, then you need to place the code after you read the operator but before you enter the arguments.

Comment: Your `if (operator.equals("quit"))` should be right after taking `operator` input

Comment: Stepping through the execution in a debugger can help you understand your code. In this case, it's doing exactly what you asked -- it's asking for the arguments before checking whether it needs any.

In addition, consider using `else if` in a chain of mutually exclusive if statements. Also, `done == true` can be written more simply as `done`.

Answer (score 1):

Please be careful with the order of your if-statements. If you don’t want to ask the user to enter `arg1` and `arg2`, make sure to check if the operator is `quit` *before* asking for the user input.
As mentioned in a comment, using the debugger of your IDE in combination with debug messages, might help understand better why a certain behavior is occuring.

On top of that, it might be helpful to take a look at the `break;` statement in the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should break the loop after taking the operator input, if the input is quit.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calc{
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   boolean done = true;
  while (done == true) {
        System.out.println("Enter operator: + - * / or quit: "); //gets operator
    String operator = scan.next();
    if(operator.equals("quit")) {
        break;
    }

    System.out.println("Enter arg1: "); //gets the first argument
    double arg1 = scan.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Enter arg2: "); //gets the second argument
    double arg2 = scan.nextDouble();

    if (operator.equals("+")) {
        add(arg1, arg2);
    }
    if (operator.equals("-")) {
        minus(arg1, arg2);
    }
    if (operator.equals("*")) {
        multiply(arg1, arg2);
    }
    if (operator.equals("/")) {
        divide(arg1, arg2);
    }
    if((!operator.equals("+")) && (!operator.equals("-") && (!operator.equals("/")) && (!operator.equals("*")) && (!operator.equals("quit")))) {
        System.out.println("Error. That is not a supported operator.");
    }
    
}
}
    static void divide (double arg1, double arg2){
        System.out.println(arg1 + "/" + arg2 + " = " + (arg1 / arg2));
    

    }

    static void multiply (double arg1, double arg2){
        System.out.println(arg1 + " * " + arg2 + " = " + (arg1 * arg2));
    

    }

    static void add (double arg1, double arg2){
        System.out.println(arg1 + " + " + arg2 + " = " + (arg1 + arg2));
    

    }

    static void minus (double arg1, double arg2){
        System.out.println(arg1 + " - " + arg2 + " = " + (arg1 - arg2));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree, that using break is the better way of doing it. However I am a bit confused by why it does not work for you, as the following code exits when you type in "quit", and doesn´t seem to differ from what you provided.

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String operator;
    boolean quit = false;
    
    while (quit == false) {
        
        operator = scan.next();

        if (operator.equals("quit")) {quit = true;}

    }
```